# Getting Employee Address from Xero API

Tags: php, xero-api

Using Xero API for PHP, I am able to retrieve a list of employees by using the following:

```
$xero->load('PayrollAU\\Employee')->execute();
```

However, this does not return the employees address. Other information is returned (name, email, gender, etc) but not the address.

How do I retrieve the employee's address?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, Xero doesn't send all the information in that particular call

In order to get all the information you have to run two calls

the first:

```
$xero->load('PayrollAU\\Employee')->execute();
```

From the result set, fetch the EmployeeID

then run another call

```
$xero->loadByGUID('PayrollAU\\Employee',$employeeID);
```

The loadByGUID call will pull all the employee data to use.